# Trying to remove border outline when tap in slides in AMP page using amp-carousel

Tags: amp-html

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bncna.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0eNZ.png)

I need to remove black border outline when tapping on the slide, Here is the reference code

Note: Please remove One two three amp-carousel and keep 4th.
And try to tap on the slide then you can answer my query.
I have tried this **.I-AMPHTML-SLIDESCROLL-no-snap .I-AMPHTML-slide-item {outline: none;}**

But it works but however if I go to AMP validator it shows the error:
**"The text inside tag 'style amp-custom' contains 'CSS I-AMPHTML- name prefix', which is disallowed."**

Added in 2nd image Screenshot but validator throughs me:|
Is there any fix please help me thanks!

https://playground.amp.dev/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fpreview.amp.dev%2Fdocumentation%2Fexamples%2Fcomponents%2Famp-carousel&format=websites&_gl=1*1roqys1*_ga*YW1wLUdDRUFRR0Q3RndwbWRGc2JQdVpsZlE.

Answer (score 1):

Replaced script tags from

to

Please refer the documentation may be they have updated the bug error.
https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-carousel/

Answer (score 0):

try this out.

```
.i-amphtml-slides-container {
  outline: none;
}
```

it worked here. Tell me if it works for u too.

Comment: I inspected your code and started to test the divs that were inside the amp carousel. Then it worked with a div with the class "i-amphtml-slides-container". Always when I am having difficulty finding out how to customize something with amp, I make this kind of test. Maybe it can be helpful for you hehe